# Open in explorer view programatically

Tags: list, solution-package, explorer

I want to open a list in Explorer mode programmatically. As we can't use javascript, what will be the approach and which WSP builder project will we create (I mean webpart, event handler, workflow?

I am using SharePoint 2007 and Visual studio 2008.